# Inserting an XML node in C# and getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception

Thanks for taking the time to possibly help me out!

I am currently having two problems, and I think that one is causing the other. Basically I am trying to insert an extra node into an existing XML file, and then fill it with data from a dataGridView. Here is the XML I am trying to change, i need to add the "Language" tag:

```
<stentry>
  <index>28</index>
  <sid>PARAM_TITLE1</sid>
  <val>
    <en>Param 1</en>
    <es>parÃ¡metro 1</es>
    ***<Language>String<language>***
  </val>
  <params>
    <fontref>187</fontref>
    <numref>0</numref>
    <clip>FALSE</clip>
    <include>FALSE</include>
    <protected>FALSE</protected>
    <cwidth>-1</cwidth>
    <dwidth>0</dwidth>
  </params>
</stentry>
```

However I am also faced with the issue that the  tag is used elsewhere:

```
<module>
  ..
  <color>
    <name>DIALOG</name>
    <val>ffd4dbee</val>
   <id>41a</id>
  </color>
  <color>
    <name>WIDGET_FILL</name>
    <val>ffc0c0c0</val>
    <id>41c</id>
 </color>
 ..
</module>
```

Currently I am using this method to insert the data:

```
int n = 0;

XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("val");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    if (node.OuterXml.Contains("val"))
    {
        XmlElement newElement = xDoc.CreateElement(tag);
        **string data = dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value.ToString();**
        XmlText txtVal = xDoc.CreateTextNode(data);
        XmlNode parent1 = node.ParentNode;
        parent1.AppendChild(newElement);
        parent1.LastChild.AppendChild(txtVal);
        n++;
    }
}
```

The problem being that at the moment I get a NullReferenceException on the highlighted line. I believe this is because there is data being put into the incorrect  tags ahead of where it needs to be. So when it tries to put data in where it is needed the value is null. But I am not 100% on this, so I have come seeking help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is null.

Comment: This would mean that `dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value` is null, did you check the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line you have highlighted is throwing a `NullReferenceException` then it isn't your XML that is faulty, it's your accessing of a cell in `dataGridView1`. Stick a breakpoint on that line, and when you hit it, inspect the properties down the chain to see where the `null` is coming. This should help you see where the exact problem is. You can do this by hovering over each property in turn when the breakpoint is on that line.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, how do I "inspect the properties down the chain"?

Comment: @OwenGarland: If you're running a debugger (such as Visual Studio) then put a breakpoint on that line and hover over the items in that line of code to see what's `null`, or look at them in the various debugging windows in the IDE.  (My personal favorite is just entering the object into the `Command` window.)  If you're not using a debugger, you can take the "defensive programming" approach and manually check for `null` values in the code before trying to use them, throwing specific errors when you find one.  Then you'd know which line threw the error and, thus, which object is `null`.

Comment: Have expanded the answer a little.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am still unsure of how I can view the value from the debugger, I am using VS 2012.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line (click in the grey margin, or press F9). Then run the code, and when it hits that line, it will stop and the line will be highlighted. Hover your mouse over various points of the code at that point in time, and you will see the values of the various bits and pieces.

Comment: So at the moment all i can ascertain is data = null; Would there be a way for me to check if dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value equals null, and then if so set data to something else.

Comment: Because would the ToString() function not work if the data was Null?